# ReactJS unable to edit the textbox created through state variable

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code where the issue is the `amount1` which the textbox is created through `state` is unable to edit. When i edit this textbox the value `10` is not changing from the textbox. The other normal textbox works as usual. Anyone knows the issue?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.state = {
        amount1:"10",
        amount2:"20",
        input:"",
    }
}
componentDidMount(){
    var options = <input type="text"  name="amount1" value={this.state.amount1}>
    this.setState({'input':options})
}
render() {
  return(
    <div>
        {this.state.input}
        <input type="text"  name="amount2" value={this.state.amount2}>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the close tag of input and since you are passing value from the state the input becomes read-only. So try **defaultValue** instead of **value** to make it editable.

Comment: In an event handler if i use `event.target.value` to get this value does it works fine?

Comment: Yes you can get it from `event.target.value`

Answer (score 0):

**Both** your inputs don't change their value since they are bound to the values in the state,
[this is your code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vvv2wolwm7)

What you need to do is add an event handler to your input tag that changes the value saved in the state.

```
handleAmountInput = (event) => { this.setState({ amount: event.target.value }) }

render() {
return( this.handleAmountInput(event)} value={this.state.amount}> ) 
    }
```

And you should close your input tag `<input />`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you changed your `render` to the following, along w/ the `onChange` binding event, you should get the appropriate values in state.

```
  onChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="amount1"
          value={this.state.amount1}
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          name="amount2"
          value={this.state.amount2}
          onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

As mentioned previously, you are creating readOnly, uncontrolled elements. This is a good article on controlled (react recommended) vs uncontrolled:
https://goshakkk.name/controlled-vs-uncontrolled-inputs-react/